# Описать разный вывод текста с помощью php на сайте Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Здравствуйте! Помогите пожалуйста разобраться вот с каким вопросом.

Есть код

```
 <? if (strlen($arResult['DETAIL_TEXT']) > 0){?>
<div class="text_all">
<div class="article-detail" id="detail_text" style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><?=$arResult['DETAIL_TEXT']?></div>

<div class="find_show">
<div class="show_text">
<div id="detail_text_resize" onclick="this.style.display='none';document.getElementById('detail_text_minimize').style.display='inline-block';document.getElementById('detail_text').style.overflow='';document.getElementById('detail_text').style.height='auto';" style="display:none;"><img src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/images/view-the-entire-text.png" style="margin-right:5px;">показать полностью</div>
<div id="detail_text_minimize" onclick="this.style.display='none';document.getElementById('detail_text').style.height='<?=$arResult['PROPERTIES']['RESIZE_TEXT']['VALUE']?>';document.getElementById('detail_text_resize').style.display='inline-block';document.getElementById('detail_text').style.overflow='hidden';" style="display:none;"><img src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/images/view-the-entire-text_back.png" style="margin-right:5px;">свернуть</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?}?>
```

Он выводит детальный текст в карточку, а скрипт задает условие, что если высота текста больше 200, то он сворачивается до 93 с возможностью развернуть подробнее.

Мне необходимо, чтобы контетник мог сам задавать высоту видимого текста, либо оставлять текст полным, не сворачивая его. Для этого я добавила пользовательское поле ['RESIZE_TEXT'], которое можно задать вручную и с помощью переменной ($arResult['PROPERTIES']['RESIZE_TEXT']['VALUE']), вместо 93px по умолчанию, передает заданное значение.

Получилось регулировать видимую зону текста, когда он сворачивается.

Но никак не могу добиться того, чтобы он, если значение поля RESIZE_TEXT = 0, то текст выводился без изменений полный и не сворачивался. Пробовала в тупую

```
   <? if ((strlen($arResult['DETAIL_TEXT']) > 0) && ($arResult['PROPERTIES']['RESIZE_TEXT']['VALUE']) = 0){?>
   <div class="text_all">
   <div class="article-detail" id="detail_text" style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><?=$arResult['DETAIL_TEXT']?></div>
   <?}?>
```

Но фокус не удался, хотя мне кажется, что выглядит все логично. Как же правильно написать эти условия?

UPD

Исправила ошибку в синтаксисе и текст начал появляться полный, но вместе с его свернутой версией. Пытаюсь написать функцию, где объясняется при каких условиях что выводить, но не работает. Подозреваю, что снова не верный синтаксис

```
 <? if ((strlen($arResult['DETAIL_TEXT']) > 0) && ($arResult['PROPERTIES']['RESIZE_TEXT']['VALUE']) == 0) {
 echo '
 <div class="text_all">
 <div class="article-detail" id="detail_text" style="margin-bottom: 15px;"><?=$arResult['DETAIL_TEXT']?></div>
 </div>';
 }
 else
 echo '
 <div class="text_all">
 <div class="article-detail" id="detail_text" style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><?=$arResult['DETAIL_TEXT']?></div>

 <div class="find_show">
 <div class="show_text">
 <div id="detail_text_resize" onclick="this.style.display='none';document.getElementById('detail_text_minimize').style.display='inline-block';document.getElementById('detail_text').style.overflow='';document.getElementById('detail_text').style.height='auto';" style="display:none;"><img src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/images/view-the-entire-text.png" style="margin-right:5px;">показать полностью</div>
<div id="detail_text_minimize" onclick="this.style.display='none';document.getElementById('detail_text').style.height='<?=$arResult['PROPERTIES']['RESIZE_TEXT']['VALUE']?>';document.getElementById('detail_text_resize').style.display='inline-block';document.getElementById('detail_text').style.overflow='hidden';" style="display:none;"><img src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/images/view-the-entire-text_back.png" style="margin-right:5px;">свернуть</div></div></div>';
 <? } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы допустили ошибку в коде, конкретно в условии вы не сравниваете переменную с 0, а присваиваете переменной $arResult['PROPERTIES']['RESIZE_TEXT']['VALUE'] значение 0, вот так должно сработать:

```
<? if ((strlen($arResult['DETAIL_TEXT']) > 0) && ($arResult['PROPERTIES']['RESIZE_TEXT']['VALUE']) == 0){?>
 <div class="text_all">
 <div class="article-detail" id="detail_text" style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><?=$arResult['DETAIL_TEXT']?></div>
 <?}?>
```

Comment: спасибо вам большое. Я два дня тупила над этим и не могла понять в чем проблема. А проблема в моем плохом знании синтаксиса. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста еще, эти два условия работают как "или или" ? Просто все работает, при значении 0 текст показывает полностью, но осталась кнопка "свернуть/развернуть", хотя я задала ей display: none; при выполнении второго условия

Comment: Добавила в вопрос условие, которое написала, но оно не срабатывает. Выдает ошибку

Comment: Уберите вообще эту строку с этого условия и не будет выводить

Comment: я ее убрала, он все-равно выводит. Один полный текст и тот же текст, но в свернутом виде

Comment: Возможно в else обернули не весь код, я не вижу весь код, подсказать с этим не смогу